# How to stack two measures while leaving the rest as single columns in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

What I am trying to accomplish is something as the image below:

[Stacked Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b28lk.png)

However, I cannot get beyond the next point in Tableau:
[Tableau Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOpfE.png)

What I need is just to have the "Tap Weight" measure as a single column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way for you to accomplish this would be to make two worksheets, one with tap weight and one with your other two weights displayed as bar charts. Then you make a dashboard and pull in both of the sheets side by side. You can hide the headers/make one header, and then make sure the axes are the same.
[image: Bar Chart Sample]